# How to subtract two sql timestamp fields then return time difference in hours

Tags: mysql, sql, metabase

I'm using open source db, metabase, and I tried `datediff()` function and it returns in day (`datediff(d1,d2)`),

but I want it returns in hours:

```
select d1,d2,d1-d2
```

and it returns

```
'2020/01/30 T00:00:00.000Z' '2020/01/28 T19:17:39.000Z' 25,158,264
```

how could I do to change it in hours? Thanks in advance.

btw timestampdiff does not work in my db version, so I might need another solution

Comment: 1) You may use TIMEDIFF() and obtain the difference in TIME datatype. The difference must NOT exceed 1 month. 2) You may convert operands to TIMESTAMP, substract (obtaining the difference in seconds) and convert to hours.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual for [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

> SELECT d1,d2,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, d1, d2) FROM *table*

Comment: hi @stacker, timestampdiff does not work in my db version, so is there another way to do so? thanks

Comment: @JamieKuo which version do you use?

Comment: hi @stacker, i checked with admin, they said there's some parameter errors, and it works now after they refresh the environment. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT 
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,d1,d2)
  AS 'Difference in Hours';

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you are using MySQL.

This is the syntax:

```
select TIMEDIFF('2020/01/30 T00:00:00.000Z','2020/01/28 T19:17:39.000Z')
```